# How to define default & non-default constructors, along with mutator and accessor methods

Tags: bluej

Creating a basic class here (Student) and needed help with confirming whether the default & non-default constructors were properly defined and how to implement the mutator and accessor methods.

```
public class STUDENT
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone_no;
    private String email;

    /**
     * Default constructor for objects of class STUDENT
     */
    public STUDENT()
    {
        name = "";
        address = "";
        phone_no = "";
        email = "";
    }

    /**
     * Non-default constructor for objects of class STUDENT
     */
    public STUDENT (String newName, String newAddress, String newPhone_no, String newEmail)
    {
        name = newName;
        address = newAddress;
        phone_no = newPhone_no;
        email = newEmail;
    }

    /**
     * The mutator method (set) for the field of name.
     */
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        name
    }

    /**
     * The accessor method (get) for the field of name.
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine in the constructors. For setter methods, you just set the global variable equal to the variable in the parameter. For getter methods, you just return the global variable with the same name. I'm not really sure what else you might be asking here

Answer (score 0):

As far as constructors go, yes they have been defined correctly. As long as the "signature" of the constructors are separate then the class will compile.

With regards to the accessor (get) and mutator (set) methods, the following is used:

Accessor:

```
public void getName()
{
   return name;
}
```

Mutator:

```
public String setName(String name)
{
   this.name = name;
}
```

Following this will help your code :)